# Table already exists error when replacing yaml by XML

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, migration, liquibase

I am trying to run some migrations on my MySQL database.While using db.changelog-master as a yaml file everything worked fine. I intend to use a xml file as db.changelog so I added  `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` to my properties and created this two xml files

### db.changelog-master.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="/db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
    <include file="/db/changelog/db.changelog-2.0.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

### db.changelog-1.0.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
 
    <changeSet author="gunter" id="changelog-1.0">
        <createTable tableName="employee">
            <column name="id" type="serial" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
        <rollback>
            <dropTable tableName="employee"/>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
 
</databaseChangeLog>
```

When I try to run my project I get the following error

### Error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-25 21:56:26.319 ERROR 13920 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::changelog-1.0::gunter:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'employee' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE test.employee (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.tutorial.demo.TutorialApplication.main(TutorialApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::changelog-1.0::gunter:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'employee' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE test.employee (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::changelog-1.0::gunter:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'employee' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE test.employee (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::changelog-1.0::gunter:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'employee' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE test.employee (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:124) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$null$0(Liquibase.java:273) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:222) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:272) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2322) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:216) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:322) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:275) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml::changelog-1.0::gunter:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'employee' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE test.employee (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:672) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:49) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$null$0(ChangeLogIterator.java:111) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$run$1(ChangeLogIterator.java:110) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:222) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:94) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:222) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:226) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:66) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'employee' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE test.employee (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:393) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:82) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:150) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1275) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1257) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'employee' already exists
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:762) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:646) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:389) ~[liquibase-core-4.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 90 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I guess is some kind of error in keeping track of the migrations already made

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @SzaPe's answer about the checksums is absolutely correct, there's another thing that should have been done - writing `preConditions` for your changeSets.

With `preConditions` your changeSet will looks like:

```
<changeSet author="gunter" id="changelog-1.0">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="employee"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="employee">
        <column name="id" type="serial" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <rollback>
        <dropTable tableName="employee"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

So when you execute the xml changeSet the preCondition will check for `employee` table existance and if that table exists, the changeSet itself will not be executed but it'd be marked as "ran" in `databasechangelog` due to `onFail="MARK_RAN"` attribute.

Check out the [docs on preconditions](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/preconditions.html).

Comment: So If I write the pre conditions do I still need to calculate the checksums?

Comment: No, you won't have to. The checksums will be different, so if your preConditions will fully describe what happens in the changeSet, all your changesets will be skipped due to preConditions failure. And the new changeSet's checksums will be added to databasechangelog table

Comment: So this means that if I want to integrate Liquibase into an existing project and run the ```generateChangeLog``` command for providing me the DB state, I still need to go through the generated changeset and write the preConditions?

Answer (score 2):

Each changeset has its unique checksum calculated and stored in a dedicated liquibase metadata table. As the yaml file resulted in different checksum than the xml, liquibase doesn't recognise the first changeset as one that was already executed and tries to apply it again. You can try the [clearChecksum](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/clearchecksums.html) command to remove the already calculated state and have it recalculated on next startup.

Alternatively you can ask liquibase to calculate it for you and you can update the metadata table in the DB to match the one form the XML, so it won't try to run it again. [calculateChecksum](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/calculatechecksum.html).

The metadata table name is `DATABASECHANGELOG` by default.